# Django model form, adding a user id when creating new note

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm pretty new to Django, I've been stuck on this view for a little while. My goal with this form is to be able to create a small note on a "Property" about maintenance or other information. The note would log the time, date, note and the user that recorded the note. Any help would be appreciated.

View:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def createNote(request, pk):
PropertyNoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Property, PropertyNote, fields=('note', 'user',))
property_note = Property.objects.get(id=pk)
form = PropertyNoteFormSet(instance=property_note)

# form = OrderForm(initial={'customer': customer})
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.POST)
    form = PropertyNoteFormSet(
        request.POST, instance=property_note)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/")

context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "dashboard/create_note.html", context)
```

Here is the ModelForm:

```
 class PropertyNoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = PropertyNote
      fields = ['note']
      exclude = ['user']
```

Here is the Model:

```
 class PropertyNote(models.Model):
        airbnb_name = models.ForeignKey(Property, blank=True, 
        null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.note
```

The form comes out with around 4 boxes to fill in. Currently it works, but you have to actually select the user that is posting the note, I would like this part to be handled automatically and use the current logged in user. I think I still have a whole lot of holes in my knowledge around this stuff, I just can't seem to work it out.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I've tried this:

```
def createNote(request, pk):
PropertyNoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Property, PropertyNote, fields=('note',), extra=1)
property_note = Property.objects.get(id=pk)
form = PropertyNoteFormSet(
    queryset=PropertyNote.objects.none(), instance=property_note)

# form = OrderForm(initial={'customer': customer})
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.POST)
    form = PropertyNoteFormSet(
        request.POST, instance=property_note)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        print(instance.user)
        instance.save()
        return redirect("/")

context = {
    "form": form,
    'pk': pk,
}
return render(request, "dashboard/create_note.html", context)
```

But I get this:

```
AttributeError at /create_note/75/
'list' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_note/75/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'list' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `request.user.id` to get the logged user id in your view.

[See Documentation in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Comment: Yeah, I've read the documentation but I can't seem to understand it. When i return the ID It gives an error of not being able to find the user. The example I've posted above is the only way i could get it to work, but i have to manually allocated the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def createNote(request, pk, **kwargs):
    note_form = PropertyNoteForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        note_form = PropertyNoteForm(request.POST)
        if note_form.is_valid():
            add_note = note_form.save(commit=False)
            add_note.user = request.user
            add_note.airbnb_name = 
      Property.objects.get(id=pk)
            add_note.save()
            return redirect('/property/' + pk + '/')

    context = {
        "form": note_form,
        'pk': pk,
    }
    return render(request, "dashboard/create_note.html", context)
```

I solved it with the above code. Using instance was the incorrect thing to do here. I didn't need to create an instance and I didn't need the inline form. I simply needed a new form:

```
note_form = PropertyNoteForm()
```

The user input information, I need to send that information to check if it's valid:

```
if request.method == "POST":
note_form = PropertyNoteForm(request.POST)
if note_form.is_valid():
```

Then I needed to populate the form with information that was not already in the form from the user:

```
add_note = note_form.save(commit=False)
add_note.user = request.user
add_note.airbnb_name = Property.objects.get(id=pk)
add_note.save()
return redirect('/property/' + pk + '/')
```